# One table or four?

Tags: database-design

I have four entities:

```
Absence { ID, StartDate, EndDate, Days, Hours, Reason }

Overtime { ID, Reason, Date (Integer), Hours (Integer) }

Time in lieu { ID, Reason, Date, Hours }

Holiday { ID, StartDate, EndDate, Days, Hours, Reason, Approved(Yes/No) }
```

I am not sure what relationship would each entity going to have with each other, It may sounds like a business decision but I believe DBAs may help me simplify this process.

I want to relate Absences with TimeInLieu, this going to be a many to many relations.

Please note I am not down to use SQL (at least at this point), I will be using SharePoint lists( which doesn't support much of relationships) but I will be doing this in Code (C#) or JS.

Also I am open to change of design.

I know how to do relationships in SharePoint or SQL, it's just I am not able to develop a successful entity diagram.

Comment: Looks good to me. AFAIK.

Comment: Many to Many relationships are managed, often times with a junction table containing row identifiers from both tables.  Absence and Time in lieu would relate to each other through this table with something like an AbsenceID and TimeInLieuID.  This way you can maintain 1 to many relationships.